# basic question about irreducible representation

Tags: representation-theory

Let $G$ be group acting linearly on a (possibly infinite dimensional) vector space $V$ (over $\mathbb{C}$ or any field). Let $v \in V$. Let $G(v)$ be the $\mathbb{C}$-span of the set $\{g\cdot v \mid g \in G \}$. Is $G(v)$ an irreducible $G$ representation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily. As a trivial example, let $V=\Bbb CG$, the group algebra,
and $v=1$. Then $G(v)=\Bbb CG$ which is only irreducible when $|G|=1$.

Comment: what is an example of a subrepresentation of $\mathbb{C}G$?

Comment: @usr0192 The kernel of the augmentation map.

Answer (score 0):

In fact in some sense the opposite of what you say is true in general.

If $V$ and $W$ are non-isomorphic irreducible representations of $G$ and $v \in V \oplus W$ is not contained entirely in either factor then $G(v)$ generates all of $V \oplus W$. In particular the set of vectors in $V \oplus W$ that generate an irreducible representation is of lower dimension and hence measure zero. You can generalize this to more factors too if you like.